# Parameterized controller constructor never gets hit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ioc-container, turbine

With my pet project I'm trying to learn to use Turbine as a DI container.

I'm registering unity as locatorprovider as such:

```
static MvcApplication()
{
    ServiceLocatorManager.SetLocatorProvider(() => new UnityServiceLocator());
}
```

My user repository has a parameterless constructor and I'm registering it as such:

```
public class UserRepositoryRegistration : IServiceRegistration
{
    public void Register(IServiceLocator locator)
    {
        locator.Register<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
    }
}
```

Then I have my HomeController which should accept an IUserRepository

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserRepository userRepository;

    public HomeController(IUserRepository repository)
    {
        userRepository = repository;
    }
}
```

If I leave out the parameterless ctor (like in the above code snippet) I get this ([full here](http://pastebin.ca/1706871)):

```
 Server Error in '/' Application.
 No parameterless constructor defined for this object.   
 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.  
 Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.  
 [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'Boris.BeekProject.Guis.Web.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
```

So my HomeController is obligated to have a parless ctor.
It seems it's not the Unity controller factory that's instantiating, but rather the default one.

**UPDATE**
My MVCApplication is inheriting TurbineApplication and since the RouteRegistration is picked up just fine I think the problem lies somewhere else.

**UPDATE**
As suggested by Thomas Eyde I wanted to override the `TurbineApplication.AutoComponent` method, but checking the Object Browser, I can't see any reference to this method.
Furthermore when I look at the NerdDinner example, it doesn't seem to override this method either.
After checking the [online documentation about it](http://mvcturbine.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AutoRegistration&referringTitle=Documentation) I failed to get any the wiser and following the link to documentation about [doing the registration manually](http://mvcturbine.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ManualRegistration&referringTitle=AutoRegistration) serves me a placeholder page.
Can anybody fill me on on what I'm doing wrong?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Also, any hints on formatting this exception would be nice. I posted a related issue on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32264/posting-a-stack-trace

Comment: Have you inherit the TurbineApplication class to you Global.asax MvcApplication class?

Comment: @Magnus: Yes, it is inheritting from TurbineApplication. The weird thing is that the IRouteRegistration is picked up fine.

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: 2 (beta) I know it's not officially supported, but I don't think that's the problem here.

Comment: Can you, just for the sake of it, try out the same code in ASP.NET MVC 1? Maybe it is the problem...

Comment: As you can read in a post by Javier himself it is indeed the V2 problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build of Turbine doesn't support MVC2, in which the ControllerFactory is changed to support an extra parameter for the creation of controllers. This is explains why your controller never gets instantiated correctly. [The breaking changes of MVC2 list this change.](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=157072)

If you're wanting to use MVC2 Beta (for .NET4) for your development, I suggest you get the new  [MVC2 (.NET4) bits I just released.](http://bit.ly/8XWZFD)

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: Thanks. I haven't had time for this pet project lately, but next week I will have some time to spare I think. I will definitely check it out then. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem, Boris. I completely understand. One question, are you using Turbine with MVC2 with .NET4 or .NET3.5? Reason I ask is because I'm in the process of getting Turbine compiled against the MVC2 RC bits that run on top of .NET3.5, so you could benefit from that update as well.

Comment: Hi Javier, thanks for the support so far in my various questions :)
It's still plain old 3.5 ;)

Comment: Ah, only now do I see the meaning of your post. As the project is in 3.5 (C#3) I'll have to wait around for the bits to hit the web.
If I'm not mistaking there is no SVN branch I can use to compile it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the `TurbineApplication.AutoComponentSetup`-method, something like this:

```
protected override void AutoComponentSetup(IServiceLocator locator)
{
    //Remove this if you want to skip all other previous registrations
    base.AutoComponentSetup(locator);

    AutoRegistration<IMyCustomInterface>((loc, type) => loc.Register<IMyCustomInterface>(type));
}
```

See also [Auto Registration for Components](http://mvcturbine.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AutoRegistration&referringTitle=Documentation)

Comment: Ah yes, that probably fills in the gap :) Thanks

Comment: after testing it out, it didn't work after all. Please ref update in OP.